# css 2 column left fixed-only-by-image-width, right col to take up rest of container width

Tags: html, css

I think my title says it all.

I need a two column css div structure.  The left column, I'm going to place an image.  The image will have a variable width, and I want the right column to take up the rest of the container.  I have this, which doesn't really work, because the right column takes up only as much room as is required.  I want the right col to take up the whole of the right side of the div containing the image.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
    <style>
.container {
   height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
    width: auto;
    float: right;
    background: #aafed6;
}

.left {
    float: none; /* not needed, just for clarification */
    background: #e8f6fe;
    /* the next props are meant to keep this block independent from the other floated one */
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}​​

    </style>


<div class="container">
    <div class="right">
        right content 
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        left content flexible width left content flexible width left content flexible width left content flexible width left content flexible width
    </div>
</div>
```

With Respect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your base is the good technique , except that `.left` should be the one `float`ting and first in the flow.

---

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/diJAj)**

---

other techniques, *if you do not want to switch div position in your `HTML`*, would be

- `display:table` + `direction` **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ovxKE)**

or

- `display:flex;` + `order`  **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Daght)**